# update portlet without refreshing portal page

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, websphere-6.1

I'm trying to create a simple agena portlet.
Now I've developed a basic one using spring-portlet-mvc, it allows you to navigate to the next and previous month with thusly named links that invoke a previousMonth or nextMonth function in my controller.
Now the problem I'm having is that this navigation causes my whole page to refresh.

Now I was wondering what the best way to fix this was.
I've been looking around a bit and it looks like jquery/ajax will do the trick, but since I don't have any experience yet with that technology I was wondering if anyone had any pointers/better ideas to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to get it with following URL for spring MVC 2.5.x.

http://www.jtraining.com/blogs/ajax-with-spring-mvc-and-jquery.html

Also check following post,

[Portlet URL Generation From AJAX Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222948/portlet-url-generation-from-ajax-servlet)

In spring MVC 3.x, Ajax support is inbuilt now. So you will find it from springsource.

Parth.